# Left area of section in iPhone TableView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

I have a section where I would like to customize the left area of a section a TableView - a bit like viewForHeaderInSection.

I have thought at using a cell for the section instead, but it would be a lot of nitty-gritty.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you want to achieve? give example screenshot maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to customise the left-hand-side of some, or every cell in a `UITableView`? Then you need to make create your own custom table view cells.  I normally make these cells in Interface Builder; this [post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/table-view-cells-in-interface-builder.html) helped me out.  See also the [Customizing Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) section of Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

I read your question to mean that there is one custom element to the left of a bunch of cells.  The only way I know of offhand is to use a cell as you describe and then have a left view and a tableview inside of it.